# Tkinter GUI counter not counting Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, counter

My program should be a very simple counter, but yet m not able to figure why it is not counting when the button clicked.

```
from tkinter import *

class Counter:

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.__value = 0
        self.__main_window = Tk()

        self.__current_value = Label(self.__main_window, text=self.__value)
        self.__current_value.pack()
        
        self.__increase_button = Button(self.__main_window, text='Increase',
                                        command=self.increase)

    def increase(self):
        self.__value += 1

def main():

    Counter()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you mean to not indent `def increase()` that far?

Comment: Hi, Sorry It was placed with extra 4 empty spaces, I have fixed it now. But now it is how originally in my code, which is not working

Comment: I've answered with the crux of the issue however I also note that your `self.__increase_button` button is never packed to the GUI and won't be displayed. You might want to add `self.__increase_button.pack()` after declaring the variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for assisting in those as well, I am new with GUI so I keep forgetting those little details. It helped much your comment about it also !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text configuration of a Label in tkinter is not auto-updating. The value stored in the `self.__value` variable is evaluated and displayed as the label.

Subsequent changes to the value of `self.__value` will not be reflected in the GUI.

When you update the `self.__value` variable you will also want to reconfigure the `self.__current_value` label to reflect these changes. You can update your `increase` method to reconfigure the label like so

```py
def increase(self):
    self.__value += 1
    self.__current_value.config(text=self.__value)
```